# Alinear cards en Material Design Lite para que no alinee a partir del tamaño del card más alto

Tags: html5, css, material-design-lite

Buenos dias y gracias de antemano,

Tengo un conjunto de cards ordenados en filas de 3 cards cada una y no consigo que las cards de las filas inferiores floten hacia el elemento de encima para aprovechar el espacio. 
La siguiente fila siempre toma el elemento más grande de la fila anterior para empezar a colocar las cards.

Dejo el codepen para que se entienda mejor: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRqVMO

Answer (score -1):

Podrías usar la librería de packery de jquery

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2/dist/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container .item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
}

/* Ejemplo de altura variable */ 
.container .item:nth-child(1),
.container .item:nth-child(5) {
  height: 250px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.container').packery({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.item',
  gutter: 20
});
```

Más información del plugin: https://packery.metafizzy.co

Ejemplo funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/e7t15L3r/

Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no conocía esta librería. No es con MDL pero bien puede servirme. Le echo un ojo y te digo como me fué :)